# Why some thunders sound deeper while others sound snappier?

Tags: atmospheric-science, lightning

Why does some thunder sound deeper and lower in pitch while others sound snappier and higher in pitch? I don't think there should be any difference between the lightnings and so the thunders sound be identical in sound.

Comment: You may be interested in reading two articles by Andrew Glassner, where he describes how to generate thunder using software: [Part 1](http://www.glassner.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/CG-CGA-PDF-00-03-The-Digital-Ceraunoscope-1-Mar00.pdf) and [Part 2](http://www.glassner.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/CG-CGA-PDF-00-05-The-Digital-Ceraunoscope-2-May00.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Higher frequencies attenuate faster in air than lower frequencies. The further away a lightning flash the less high frequency components will reach your ear

Comment: Plus it dpends on many factors, the sound is produced by (charged) nebula which come into contact and discharge,as such the density/size/shape etc of nebula involved makes a difference

Comment: Also rain, cloud and moisture all affect the way sound is absorbed at different frequencies. Additionally, low frequencies suffer more diffraction effects. I suppose the complete answer is quite complex.

Comment: ok sure, but we can make it more self-contained as possible!